# Finding a value inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck with an issue, any help would be appreciated.

I have a rails query

```
array = Issue.where("tracker_id =? AND project_id = ?",8,140).first.custom_field_values
```

This returns an array like this :

```
[#<CustomFieldValue:0x000000074d8b98 @custom_field=#<IssueCustomField id: 4, type: "IssueCustomField", name: "Phase Injected", field_format: "list", possible_values: ["Planning", "Requirements", "Design", "Coding", "Testing"], regexp: "", min_length: nil, max_length: nil, is_required: true, is_for_all: true, is_filter: true, position: 4, searchable: false, default_value: "", editable: true, visible: true, multiple: false, format_store: {"url_pattern"=>"", "edit_tag_style"=>""}, description: "", formula: nil, is_computed: false>, @customized=#<Issue id: 43, tracker_id: 8, project_id: 140, subject: "Cost of rework is  not calculated for past sprints", description: "", due_date: nil, category_id: nil, status_id: 1, assigned_to_id: 5, priority_id: 2, fixed_version_id: 1, author_id: 8, lock_version: 3, created_on: "2018-07-26 05:40:19", updated_on: "2018-08-09 10:46:12", start_date: "2018-07-26", done_ratio: 0, estimated_hours: nil, parent_id: 42, root_id: 42, lft: 2, rgt: 3, is_private: false, closed_on: nil, sprint_id: nil, position: nil>, @value="Planning", @value_was="Planning">,.....]
```

The above array has more then 10 results pasted the first one.

How do I search inside this array for the name = 'Phase Injected' and get the result that is @value which is 'planning'.

Currently I am trying to go inside the array by:

```
<% array.each do |cf| %>
  <% if cf.custom_field.name = "Phase Injected" %>
    <%= cf %> #this returns @value
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

can I not do `array.find_by_something` and get the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns *the active record relation* object, not *the array* in the first place. Yes, it quacks as an array, though.

You should filter the data directly in the database instead of an extremely ineffective array filtering:

```
Issue.
  joins(:issue_custom_fields).
  where(tracker_id: 8, project_id: 140).
  where('`issue_custom_fields`.`name` = "Phase Injected"')
```

or, as @Stefan suggests in comments:

```
Issue.
  joins(:issue_custom_fields).
  where(tracker_id: 8, project_id: 140).
  where(issue_custom_fields: { name: 'Phase Injected' })
```

Comment: `where(issue_custom_fields: { name: 'Phase Injected' })` should work as well

Comment: Do you always put the `.` at the end of the line? (I'm just curious, I don't want to start a syntax war)

Comment: @Stefan yes; that way it’s copy-paste-to-console friendly. Neither `pry` nor `irb` would understand they are to wait for the dot at the next line.

Comment: (Trailing dots also allow in-line comments)

Comment: @matthewd true, but I personally prefer comments in the end of line which are allowed in both cases.